# Erro ao executar código pycuda: "nvcc fatal : Value 'sm_61' is not defined for option 'gpu-architecture"

Tags: python-3.x, cuda

Acabei de instalar o pycuda no Ubuntu 16.04 e estou tentando verificar se está funcionando.
Estou tentando executar:

```
#https://documen.tician.de/pycuda/tutorial.html

import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule


import numpy
a = numpy.random.randn(4,4)


a = a.astype(numpy.float32)

a_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(a.nbytes)

cuda.memcpy_htod(a_gpu, a)


mod = SourceModule("""
  __global__ void doublify(float *a)
  {
    int idx = threadIdx.x + threadIdx.y*4;
    a[idx] *= 2;
  }
  """)
```

Erro:

```
pycuda.driver.CompileError: nvcc compilation of /tmp/tmpzohid21m/kernel.cu failed
[command: nvcc --cubin -arch sm_61 -I/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pycuda/cuda kernel.cu]
[stderr:
nvcc fatal   : Value 'sm_61' is not defined for option 'gpu-architecture'
]
```

Alguma ideia de como resolver?

Comment: Qual a versão do Cuda ?

Comment: @NoobSaibot: CUDA 9.2 Alguma ideia?

Comment: Esse [tópic](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1038841/pycuda-error-ldquo-nvcc-fatal-value-sm_61-is-not-defined-for-option-gpu-architecture-rdquo-/) foi você quem criou ? Tem [esse outro](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1024670/cuda-programming-and-performance/trouble-with-python-import-of-cuda/).

Comment: @NoobSaibot: Sim. Apenas o primeiro No forum da Nvidia!

Comment: @NoobSaibot: Pensei que ia conseguir instalar o pycuda e sair usando... Estou quase desistindo!